How to interpret ambiguous phrases like "John knows the father of Sam and Leon" with no context?
I was frequently puzzuled by sentences with the following structure:

John knows the father of Sam and Leon.

I suppose there are two different understandings:

John knows one person who is the father of both Sam and Leon;
John knows two people: Sam's father and someone named Leon.

Within the technical papers I met, there are few contexts helpful to clarify the ambiguity. So I am begging for a rule of thumb to catch the real meaning.
I really appreciate any advice and keywords.

Supplementary about the context:
In fact I was reading a wiki page about some cache strategy of computer science, i.e., MESI protocol.
The sentence is:

Received by sender of BusRdx and Memory Controller, which writes to Main memory.

I was puzzled at first glance -- what is the sender of Memory Controller? And then I realized that the object of received is sender of BusRdx and Memory Controller.
It is possible that I took more time to figure out the ambiguity, but it worries me that if I were not familiar with this jargon, I could run in the wrong direction.

It would be a highly unlikely way of expressing the second meaning, so hardly anyone would understand it that way. We would say something like "John knows Sam's father, and Leon too."

It is silly to ask for a 'rule of thumb' to allow resolve without-context ambiguities, (especially those concocted for the purpose!) when it is precisely context that allows ambiguity to be resolved. That, and sensible construction of utterances and writings.

As you surmise, the phrase "the father of Sam and Leon" can mean either "the father of both Sam and Leon" or "Sam's father and Leon"; but in general, we prefer "X's father" over "the father of X" when X is just a single name, which means that "Sam's father and Leon" is unlikely to be expressed as "the father of Sam and Leon" (especially if the writer has any sense).
But I assume that the technical papers you mention are not actually using the phrase "the father of Sam and Leon", but rather, some more complicated expression of the form "the X of Y and Z"; so the above point is unlikely to be helpful. I think I naturally read "the X of Y and Z" as "the X of {Y and Z}" unless it's somehow obvious that it's meant to be read as "{the X of Y} and Z"; and I would hope that if the authors intended the latter meaning and this wasn't otherwise obvious, that they would notice the potential ambiguity and rephrase it as "Z and the X of Y"; but there is really no guarantee. (For one thing, "obvious" is subjective. If I wrote "the President of the United States and the British Prime Minister", I would never notice the hypothetical ambiguity whereby someone is the President of {the US and Rishi Sunak}, so it would never occur to me to rephrase it. Likewise, in the papers you're reading, the authors may consider their intended meaning perfectly obvious, so never notice the possible misinterpretation.)

The ambiguity lies in that you're attempting to interpret the written representation of a segment of a spoken conversation stripped of context, nuance, and inflection.
A normal speaker would slur over the "and" producing (phonetically) "sammin' lee on" if the two were siblings and offspring of the aforementioned father.
In the case of John's simply knowing Sam's dad and some dude named Leon, "Sam...'n' Leon" will be the phonetic expression - perhaps with a little more enunciation of "and" than depicted.
It just ain't meant to be wrote down.
